# Why is my question on hold? (similar questions received proper answers and it was not duplicate)

Tags: discussion

I asked a question about interesting Natural sights enroute from Chicago to Niagara ([What is a good way to get list of sights for a road trip (e.g. for a roadtrip from Chicago to Niagara falls?)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26432/what-is-a-good-way-how-to-get-list-of-sights-for-a-road-trip-e-g-for-a-roadtri))

It was almost immediately put on hold. I perceived this as slightly hostile.

I have tried to edit the question to be more general - how to generally obtain a list of sights around any given route. But (I assume) since it is on hold, no one is providing answers. I have no way how to remove the On hold status.

I noticed today that a question very similar (not a duplicate) to my original question is receiving proper answers [Entertaining family stopovers on a driving trip from Pittsburgh, PA, to Chicago, IL](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1158/entertaining-family-stopovers-on-a-driving-trip-from-pittsburgh-pa-to-chicago?rq=1)

The other question is mentioning a toddler but we do not have any toddlers, is this the reason my question was put on hold?

Comment: Also note that the original question was during the extensive beta period, when the direction of the site was still forming. It's not that useful to try and use old questions as a basis for argument - as the style of the site has changed a lot since then.

Answer (score 7):

The [first version](https://travel.stackexchange.com/revisions/26432/1) of your question was closed because it was very much opinion-based. Since you edited it, it is in way better shape and already accumulated 3 out of 5 votes needed to reopen it. Since the question is now way better, I cast another reopening vote and the question is now open again.

If you edit your closed question, you can always flag it for moderator attention so that we can have a look at it and reopen if the question is in written in an appropriate way.